# HQL select where object1.list<object2>[0...n].Id = givenId

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

I have a class Transaction, among its parameters is List of Tag Tags.

I want to select List of Transaction by TagId?

something like this(my query is obviously wrong at the WHERE clause...:

```
transactionList = session.CreateQuery("FROM Transaction TR WHERE TR.Tags.TagId =: id")
.SetInt32("id", tId)
.List<Transaction>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
transactionList = session.CreateQuery(
    @"SELECT TR 
      FROM Transaction TR 
      JOIN TR.Tags T 
      WHERE T.TagId = :id")
.SetInt32("id", tId)
.List<Transaction>();
```